# navigate folders with python

Tags: python, directory

I have a folder ROOT and inside many different folders (let's assume N), that for sake of simplicity I call F1, F2 and so on...

I need to work with the file inside these folders.
If I have only one folder I know that I can do:

```
os.chdir(".") #I'm workingo in ROOT
for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    #I can work with the i-th file...
```

But what I need to do is something like this (pseudo-code like):

```
os.chdir(".") #I'm working in ROOT
for F-i-th in ROOT: #for each folder in the ROOT main folder
    for filename in F-i-th("*.txt"): #I select only the file with this extention
         #process data inside i-th file
```

I mean that I need to go inside the first folder (F1) and process all the file (or if it is possible all the .txt file), after I should go inside the F2 and process all the file....

Comment: Do you just want [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.walk` will perform recursion of a directory and `fnmatch.filter` will match filename patterns.  Simple example:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for path,dirs,files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files,'*.txt'):
        fullname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path,f))
        print(fullname)
```