# open folders contained in another folder

Tags: python, directory

I have a series of sub-folders contained in a main folder. I would like to get access to each sub-folder so I can use the files in it. I have tried the following but apparently my 'appending' method is not possible on Python. Can somebody help me out?

```
import os
os.chdir('C\\current folder')
for subfolder in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    os.chdir('C\\current folder\\'subfolder'')
```

Comment: `os.walk()` is your friend

Comment: Possible duplicate of [navigate folders with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549660/navigate-folders-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os.path
import glob

for subdir in glob.glob("X/certain*"):
    path = os.path.join(subdir, "result.txt")
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write("This is the result\n")
```

This code helped me a lot.Actually taken from here....but was a life saver..!

[How do I open a folder that contains files within another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43671727/7012517)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I search for `.png` files in all directories recursively under `path_to_my_root_directory` and append to a list of all files and paths to list called `fis`.

```
import os
fis=[]
rootdir=os.walk('path_to_my_root_directory`)
for root,subd,fils in rootdir :
    for name in fils:
        if name.endswith('.png'):
            fis.append(os.path.join(root,name))
```